# Incongruity between summation and proof result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

A website made the statement $P(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.

If I want to know the value at the 3rd position in the sequence is, I just plug $3$ into the equation:

$$P(3) = \sum_{n=0}^3 = i^2 = \frac{1}{6}3(3+1)(2(3)+1)$$

And the result is $\frac{84}{6} = 14$. Why is it not 4, which is the third integer generated by the summation: $0, 1, 4, 9, 16...$?

Comment: I guess that they want series start at P(1)=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing **sequences** and **series**:

---

A **sequence** is a list of numbers separated with commas. For example:
$$
1, 4, 9, 16, \ldots
$$
Notice that the $n$th term in the sequence is given by $t_n = n^2$.

---

A **finite series** is the sum of the first few terms in a sequence. For example:
\begin{align*}
s_1 &= 1 \\
s_2 &= 1 + 4 = 5 \\
s_3 &= 1 + 4 + 9 = 14 \\
s_4 &= 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30 \\
\end{align*}

---

You are being asked to prove that the sum of the first $n$ terms in the sequence is given by the formula:
$$
s_n = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was confused about. And you cleared it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you have written is correctly described by $\lbrace i^2\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, instead of $\lbrace \sum_0^i k^2\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. In fact, $0 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 1+4+9 = 14$ gives the 3rd term of the latter sequence, so it is correct.